# Strange connections by gvfsd-http --spawner

Tags: connection, gvfs, netstat

For a little while now, a strange connection has been showing up on my netstat made by the command:

```
/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-http --spawner :1.1 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/2
```

By the time I notice it, the connection is always at the closed state. Every time I trace the IP address, it usually says that no website is registered.

I am unsure what activated this. It could be one of my browsers (Chrome and Firefox). I'm getting a little worried about this.

Could someone clue me in to what this could possibly be, and how to prevent the connection.

Answer (score 8):

If the command

`sudo watch netstat -tonp`

shows a lot of connections caused by gvfs directly after booting, then you can consider to remove **zeitgeist**, **geoclue**, and/or **ubuntu-one**. You can also consider to deactivate the **rhythmbox lastfm-plugin**. As I don't need these programs I decided to remove them all and after the next boot, all strange gvfs connections disappeared.

The following page shows you how to remove some of these applications.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2000108

Be aware, that Zeitgeist is an essential part of Unity! So don't remove it, if you are using Unity.

Answer (score 3):

gvfsd is your Gnome Virtual File System.  There is a fairly old bug that causes it to leave connections in the CLOSE_WAIT state for an undefined amount of time.  It seems to be more an issue with RhythmBox more than another other program I've seen.

Some sources:

[Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1152885.html)

[Ubuntu forums 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1564418.html)

Answer (score 1):

This will help you I think, so take a look:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/571970

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `gvfsd-http` was connecting to a server called backoo.canonical.com

```
tcp  |  1  |  192.168.1.108:33427  |  backoo.canonical.com:www LAST_ACK
```

This was an IP-address of: `91.189.94.41`
It would show up whenever I ran `netstat -tu`.